# Color in bleed using pagecolor and crop

Tags: color, crop

I use `XeTeX`, `Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998` (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX).

I am using the crop package to add bleed and crop marks to a document. This works fine for pages with white background, but how do I achieve this for pages which have another colour in the bakckground?

I tried the pagecolor package, and see that it somehow extends the pagecolour to around 2 to 3 mm into the bleed but not beyond. How do I make the entire bleed region of the same colour as the page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false,paperwidth=138mm,paperheight=216mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[noaxes,noinfo,cam,dvips,pdftex,center,width=168mm,height=246mm]{crop}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{orange}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is a feature of package `crop`, which redefines the internal macro `\set@page@color`, which is called by `\pagecolor`.

The following example, restores the original meaning of `\set@page@color`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=138mm,
  paperheight=216mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\org@set@page@color\set@page@color
\makeatother

\usepackage[
  noaxes,
  noinfo,
  cam,
  center,
  width=168mm,
  height=246mm
]{crop}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\set@page@color\org@set@page@color}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \pagecolor{orange}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]