# How to avoid \pagecolor to cancel trims

Tags: color, pdf-with-trim

I need to color the background of the page. Unfortunately, command `\pagecolor` cancels trims. Is it possible to fix this? I'm using `LuaLaTex`.

Here I put an example:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,showtrims]{memoir}

\quarkmarks

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\setstocksize{178mm}{115mm}
\settrimmedsize{148mm}{100mm}{*}
\settrims{15mm}{15mm}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{yellow}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

The output page, when command `\pagecolor{yellow}` is commented looks like this:

[image]

When the `\pagecolor{yellow}` command is enabled, trims are cancelled:

[image]

With reference to the question posted in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-to-make-shaded-pages-and-still-see-memoirs-trim-frame/36430), I remark that the same problem holds using package {background} with the option {opacity = 1}.

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of this : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-to-make-shaded-pages-and-still-see-memoirs-trim-frame/36430

Comment: @koleygr No, since if I put {opacity=1} in the options, trims get covered also. I can add this in the text of my question, to make it clear.

Comment: Did you try the `crop` package like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248505/color-in-bleed-using-pagecolor-and-crop ?

Comment: I just saw that `memoir` already loads `crop`. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a fix... but don't ask about the numbers added in my tikz command:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,showtrims]{memoir}

\quarkmarks

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bophook}

\setstocksize{178mm}{115mm}
\settrimmedsize{148mm}{100mm}{*}
\settrims{15mm}{15mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginPage{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\node%[red]
at(current page.north west) {\ifodd\thepage\settrims{10.4mm}{-10.4mm}\else\relax\settrims{10.4mm}{39.9mm}
\fi%
\trimmarks};\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\pagebreak

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\pagebreak

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

You can use it for this specific settings just to do your job... Later may be I will try to find a real formula but for the moment I just found the numbers by testing and had no time to search and really understand the `.cls` code.

PS: Other users can feel free to use the idea (of the overlay) and post a better answer.

Comment: I had the same idea about the current page anchors etc, but wondered about the strange output.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried midway of north and north west and was close (one of the axis was almost perfect tuned... but the other didn't)